# After renaming SQL Server 2016 cluster there's still a trace of old name from Database Mail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, failovercluster, database-mail

I followed the Microsoft Docs and changed the name of a new SQL Server cluster I built from `SQLCLUSTER` to `SQLFC01`. I ensured everything was updated in AD and @@SYSTEMNAME returns the correct 'SQLFC01'. I'm running SQL Server 2016 Standard on SP2 and CU2.

**The problem**
When sending myself a test email via Database Mail, the name of the email shows as: "SQLCLUSTER SQL Server Admin" instead of "SQLFC01 SQL Server Admin"

I'm guessing there are remnants of the name somewhere on the server... though I've spent hours searching online and the registry but can't find anything. I'm using the same SMTP server on a handful of other servers and the email name on those show correctly as whatever their machine name is. I tried restarting services and rebooting the entire cluster - no luck.

Any ideas what I could do to fix this?

[image: Here's what the emails look like compared to other servers using the same SMTP]

[image: Proof @@SERVERNAME shows SQLFC01]

Comment: is this a WFCI or just an Instance in a WSFC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect this is simply the **Display Name** or the **Description** for the database mail account.

In SSMS

- Expand the *Management* folder
- Right click on *Database Mail*
- Select *Configure Database Mail*
- Click *Next*
- Select *Manage Database Mail accounts and profiles* and then select *Next*
- Select *View, change, or delete and existing account* and then select *Next*

I expect you will see **SQLCLUSTER SQL Server Admin** in the *Display Name* of the SMTP or in the **Description** of the *Account Name*. Change it to what ever you want.

Comment: This was actually it! Spending too much time on this build the last two days had me thinking it was something more involved and I looked over the basics. This was what I needed - much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome @TheRealCode. The clue for me was the work *Admin* in your post. That looked like something someone custom wrote.